# Using external auth providers access-token in MSAL

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-msal

I have a React application using MSAL(Microsoft Authentication). Also, I have an external application using a custom OAuth implementation. Is it possible to login into MSAL using access-token from the custom OAuth implementation